# How can I make reliable multiple choice questions in Python?

Tags: python

Ok so here's the deal:
I got a .txt file containing a Python dictionary.
I want Python to ask me to choose from the keys of the dictionary,
like this: (Let's say the .txt is {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"})

```
Choose:
 1) key1
 2) key2
 Q) Quit
[1/2/Q]: <What I chose will be here>
You chose <What I chose>.
```

Now, for a standard multiple choice question I would have done something like this:

```py
while True:
    d1a = input("Do you want to: \n 1) key1 \n 2) key2 \nQ) Quit \n[1/2/Q]? : ")
    if d1a == "1":
        var = "1"
        print("You chose " + var)
        break
    elif d1a == "2":
        var = "2"
        print("You chose " + var)
        break
    elif d1a == "Q":
        quit()
```

The problem is that if I add more keys and vaulues to the dictionary this gets pretty useless, how can I make it so the multiple choice question changes together with the dictionary?

Comment: You will need to open the file, parse its contents and iterate of the resulting dictionary's keys/values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have a control file with these contents:

```
{
"key1":"value1",
"key2":"value2",
"key3":"value3"
}
```

We can use *json* module to help load this and give us a Python dictionary.

Then build the input prompt based on the dictionary's contents. In this way the input prompt will be dynamic - i.e., no hard coding - just based on the control file's contents

```
import json


d = json.load(open('control.json'))
choices = ['Choose:\n']
fp = ['[']
for n, k in enumerate(d, 1):
    choices.append(f' {n}) {k}\n')
    fp.append(f'{n}/')
choices.append(' Q) Quit\n')
fp.append('Q]? : ')

prompt = ''.join(choices) + ''.join(fp)

while True:
    response = input(prompt)
    if response == 'Q':
        break
    # at this point you need to validate the user input for other possible values
```

In this case the input prompt would look like this:

```
Choose:
 1) key1
 2) key2
 3) key3
 Q) Quit
[1/2/3/Q]? :
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```py
dct = {
    "1": ("key1", "val1"),
    "2": ("key2", "val2"),
    "3": ("key3", "val3"),
    "4": ("key4", "val4")
}

# Creating Dynamic Question
mc_question = "Do you want to: "
for i in dct.keys():
    mc_question += f"\n {i}) {dct[i][0]} "
mc_question += "\n Q) Quit \n["
mc_question += "/".join(list(dct.keys()))
mc_question += "/Q]:"

while True:
    d1a = input(mc_question)
    if d1a == "Q": quit()
    elif d1a not in dct: print("Please enter a valid key!")
    else: print(dct[d1a][1]) # Print value
```

Output:

```
Do you want to:
 1) key1
 2) key2
 3) key3
 4) key4
 Q) Quit
[1/2/3/4/Q]:
```

Comment: nice it worked too. I guess now comes the part where i try to decrypt those. Ty both

Answer (score -1):

urm, load the dict from the .txt and just do

```py
loaded_dict = ... # the dict u loaded from the `.txt`
d1a = input("Do you want to: \n 1) key1 \n 2) key2 \nQ) Quit \n[1/2/Q]? : ")
print(loaded_dict[d1a])
```

but i would prefer u use a `.json` to store dicts instead of `.txt`, it much easier to use

Comment: The input prompt is constant and doesn't relate to the dictionary contents